# English to Morse code converter

Tags: c++, converters, helper, alphabetical, morse-code

I need to convert English letters and Arabic numbers to Morse code until `enter` is pressed. I used a `do while` loop to read letters until `enter` is pressed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int j = 0;
char a[100];
const char *latin = "**ETIANMSURWDKGOHVF?L?PJBHCYZQ??54?3??2?????6????7??890";

void dash(){cout<<"-";}
void dot(){cout<<".";}

void conv(int decimal)
{
   if(decimal){
    conv(decimal/2);
    if(decimal!=1) decimal%2 ? dash() : dot();
   }
}

void morse(char a[], int lenght)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= lenght; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z') a[i] -= 32;
        if(a[i] < 'A' && a[i] > 'Z') return;
        while(latin[++j] != a[i]);
            conv(j);

    }
}

int main()
{
    int lenght = 0;

    cout<<"letter=";

   do{
        cin>>a[lenght];
        lenght++;
    } while(0);


    morse(a, lenght);

    return 0;
}
```

When I return the length it is always one, so the function makes only one loop. Also, there are some extra symbols that appear when the code is compiled.

Comment: "_I used a do..while loop to read letters until ENTER key is pressed._" No, you didn't. The only `do`..`while` loop in the shown code does a single iteration, since `0` in `while` condition is evaluated as `false`.

Comment: Have you considered using a lookup table? Would make your life easier...

Comment: Consider `std::getline` together with a `std::string`, much easier than your loop and additionally does not limit input length.

Comment: Be aware that `-= 32` only works with ASCII and compatible character sets. While this is the vast majority, you still might want to keep in mind.

Comment: You need to reset j for each character! Prefer having it a local variable of `morse` function. `strchr` does the same as your loop...

Comment: It is hard in C++ to do something in real time until enter is pressed. C++ doesn't do much of anything UNTIL enter is pressed. If you don't care and are willing to wait on translation until enter is pressed, groovy take @Aconcagua 's advice about `getline` and `string`. If not, you'll need a console library like curses. I doubt that is what's expected of you though.

Comment: [The recommended C++ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I can't use string because it is forbidden in the task.

Comment: Have you been given a maximum valid input? In `char a[100];` you use 100. Does the assignment specify that input will not exceed 100?

Comment: I recommend @Aconcagua lookup table approach.  Use `char * pattern[26] = {/*...*/};`.  You could write `cout << pattern['E'];` as the simplest conversion.  Modern desktop computers should have enough memory to support an array of 256 elements.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things going on here, but the reason that `lenght` is always `1` is because you only run through your while loop once:

```
do {
    cin>>a[lenght];
    lenght++;
} while (0); // this will always evaluate to false
```

The `do` block above only executes once because `while (0)` evaluates to false. This means that `lenght` is only incremented once, which would explain why its value is `1`.

Here's a (potentially) better way:

```
while (cin.peek() != '\n') {
  cin >> a[lenght++];
}
```

And you can get the output you're looking for by modifying `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    int length = 0;

    cout << "letter = ";

    while (cin.peek() != '\n') {
      cin >> a[length++];
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
      morse(a[i]);
      i++;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Code**

Here it is all assembled (along with a few minor changes to `conv()` and `morse()`):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int j = 0;
char a[100];
const char *latin = "**ETIANMSURWDKGOHVF?L?PJBHCYZQ??54?3??2?????6????7??890";

void dash(){cout<<"-";}
void dot(){cout<<".";}

void conv(int decimal) {
    if (decimal) {
        conv(decimal/2);
        if (decimal != 1) decimal%2 ? dash() : dot();   
    } 
}

void morse(char c) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') c -= 32;
    if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') return;
    int i = 0;
    while (latin[++i] != c);
    conv(i);
}

int main()
{
    int length = 0;

    cout << "letter = ";

    while (cin.peek() != '\n') {
      cin >> a[length++];
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
      morse(a[i]);
      i++;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

> $ letter =  sos

**Output**

> $ ...---...

**Edit**

As pointed out by user4581301 below, this can be simplified further by removing a[] and the second loop:

```
int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    char c;

    cout << "letter = ";

    while (cin.peek() != '\n') {
      char c;
      cin >> c;
      morse(c);
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 The explanation was as a comment in the code. Moved it outside the code block. Hopefully that's a bit more clear.

Comment: and how to write it in order to to be executed until ENTER is pressed

Comment: @MartinaGeorgieva I'm still noticing other issues (like the extra characters you mentioned). Looking into that.

Comment: Thank you, now it counts right, but still after the first letter the output is not right...

Comment: @AlexJohnson Thank you very much

Comment: @MartinaGeorgieva Fun little problem. If this answered your question, please feel free to upvote and/or accept.

Comment: @MartinaGeorgieva, note that since this version of `morse` operates on a single character, you can eliminate the need for `a` and the second loop. You can read in a character, morse-ify it, and output it all in the same loop. This will allow you to handle nearly infinite input.